# Why staging command git read-tree <hash> is not working

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In O'reilly's course "Complete Git Guide: Understand and Master Git and GitHub" by  Bogdan Stashchuk. In chapter 3 Reading Files in the Staging Area Using git ls-files.

I am using git read-tree  command to  put  a file in staging area. But I am getting  error saying  "error: invalid path "file1.txt"". This particular tree contain two blob object.

```
$ find .git/objects -type f
.git/objects/13/30b1315f618bbb92980a72304d102077a06456
.git/objects/37/0d3a4362e43ff0b8b8b44dc571a4943c2ae849
.git/objects/55/7db03de997c86a4a028e1ebd3a1ceb225be238
.git/objects/9d/85f911b64dff32d66d462086e8b13207efa4c5
.git/objects/dd/1d744af6af14449fbc727490e2b90439b27ad6
.git/objects/fe/65c715aff73bceac655b9032a26658404cdcfe

  $ git cat-file -t 1330
tree 
     
$ git read-tree 1330
error: invalid path 'file1.txt
100644 blob 9d85f911b64dff32d66d462086e8b13207efa4c5    file2.txt



'
```

I created a text file on desktop and then by using command (cd nano temp-tree.txt) I edited the content of the file (100644 blob  file1.txt) similarly I wrote second blob object in that file only. After that I went inside my git repo and typed command ( cat ../temp-tree.txt | git mktree -z). Then file got created I could see that in hidden folder. Also, all cat commands are working on that.

Also, when I created new git repo , blob object , tree object and tried to use again git-read tree  command, no output was coming.
Please help.
Thank you

Comment: What is `cd nano temp-tree.txt`? That's not a valid command

Answer (score 2):

- Check the content of that tree object :

  ```
  git cat-file -p 1330
  ```
- Check what `git fsck` and git `fsck --unreachable` say

---

From the error message : it looks like git interprets everything between the two single quotes (e.g : the five lines starting at `file1.txt...` and ending with 3 empty lines) as a single path.

My guess is there is something fishy in the raw content of that tree object.

---

With the `-z` option, `mktree` expects `\0` characters (instead of `\n`) to separate values in the input. It is intended to be used in conjunction with a command that outputs `\0` characters, such as `git ls-files -z`.

Since you edited the input by hand, you didn't insert `\0` characters in your file, so `mktree` took all that came after the first hash as a single "path" (and obviously, didn't run checks on it to confirm it looked like a valid path).

If you really intend to use `git mktree` from hand typed input : drop the `-z`, and read the error messages to try to understand what doesn't fit.

(I'd guess : remove empty lines from your file, if your OS is Windows turn your line endings to "linux style")

---

Unless you are trying to explicitly understand how to use `git mktree`, you would be better off creating trees using your regular :

```
git add file1.txt file2.txt
# will create a tree and a commit :
git commit

# to get the hash of the tree :
git rev-parse HEAD^{tree}     
# or
git cat-file -p HEAD  # look for the 'tree <sha1>' line
```

or possibly :

```
git add file1.txt file2.txt
# will create only a tree, from the index :
git write-tree
```

see `git help write-tree` and `git help mktree` for some pointers, and [the git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) for a good guided tour of how objects are stored in git.

Comment: $ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
notice: No default references
dangling tree 1330b1315f618bbb92980a72304d102077a06456
dangling tree 370d3a4362e43ff0b8b8b44dc571a4943c2ae849
dangling blob 9d85f911b64dff32d66d462086e8b13207efa4c5
dangling blob dd1d744af6af14449fbc727490e2b90439b27

Comment: Also, when I created new git repo , blob object , tree object and tried to use again git-read tree command, no output is coming

Comment: Please explain how you created your tree object, then

Comment: Also : does `git cat-file -p 1330` output something ? do you have an error or a warning message when you run it ?

Comment: No, I am not getting any error until git read-tree <hash>

Comment: I created a text file on desktop and then by using command (cd nano temp-tree.txt)  I edited the content of the file (100644 blob <hash code> file1.txt) similarly I wrote second blob object in that file only. After that I went inside my git repo and typed command ( cat ../temp-tree.txt | git mktree -z). Then file got created I could see that in hidden folder. Also, all cat commands are working on that.

Comment: great, can you edit your question to add this information ? (your issue lies in `git mktree -z`)

Comment: Thank you , I have edited . Without using -z , when I was trying to make tree , I was getting error. I came to know about using -z in command on stack overflow itself. Also , can you tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `git mktree` command will (deliberately!) allow you to create a bad / invalid tree.  (This is a maintenance command, and the Git test suite uses it for these kinds of things to make sure that, e.g., `git fsck` can detect particular errors.)

You created a bad tree, then tried to use it.  That is entirely your fault: you should expect this kind of failure.

You ran `git fsck` and it did not diagnose the bad tree.  That is mostly `git fsck`'s fault: it should find and diagnose the error.  However, in this case, it's not *technically* an error: you made a tree entry whose *file name* contains a newline, which is technically allowed (but probably shouldn't be).